# Issue animating shape without leaving big gap at bottom etc - CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, animation

I am currently trying to display a shape that animates behind other divs within the same container.
Everything looks fine, until I add additional content (inside or outside the same area)

The intended result is to look like this with space below to allow for other content to be added without having huge empty space and negative margins set (as I currently do for the shape):

https://media2.giphy.com/media/TJs23q70cgnyxAwJsA/giphy.gif

What I am currently getting is more like this:

https://media3.giphy.com/media/JNshdMa1gEdtmsnDYI/giphy.gif

Here is the code that I am presently implementing ( for this particular area ):

```css
/* Blog Section */

#blog-section {
  padding-top: 7rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-display {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.blog-img img {
  text-align: center;
}

.blog-text {
  margin: auto 5rem;
  color: white;
}

.blog-text a {
  color: white;
}

.blog-plate {
  background: #0c3445;
  top: -800px;
  height: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: 20s ease-in 7s infinite blogmove;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes blogmove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -800px;
  }
  25% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -705px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -600px;
  }
  75% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -705px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -800px;
  }
}


/* Recipe Section */

#recipe-section {
  padding-top: 7rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="blog-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="blog-display">
      <div class="blog-img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NEbj5nR.jpg" alt="blog1">
      </div>
      <div class="blog-text">
        <h3>New Book By H. G. Cayton</h3>
        <p>If you haven’t been backing up to iCloud but have backed up your phone to iTunes on your Mac or PC (or to Finder, if you’re running macOS Catalina), you may be able to recover your text messages from there. And even if you think you didn’t back
          up your messages, it’s worth a few […]</p>

        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- This is the background shape I am animating -->
  <div class="blog-plate"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="another-section">
      Content within the same section
      <!-- Added content here is pushed further down below -->
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<section id="recipe-section">
  <div>
    Next Section Here, Why am I so far down?
  </div>
</section>
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am getting from your question, you want the shape to be animated just behind the upper section which have an image and content side by side and at the same time don't want the extra white space to come after that block. So if I am right, then you can achieve this by wrapping the shape which animates in one more div and place it using `position:absolute;` instead of `position:relative;` because using position `relative` and giving it `top:-800px;` is the main reason the white space after that div is created. Try the code below and let me know if it helps, I have also made few changes to the `keyframes` :-

HTML

```
<section id="blog-section">
  <div class="plate-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="blog-display">
      <div class="blog-img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NEbj5nR.jpg" alt="blog1">
      </div>
      <div class="blog-text">
        <h3>New Book By H. G. Cayton</h3>
        <p>If you haven’t been backing up to iCloud but have backed up your phone to iTunes on your Mac or PC (or to Finder, if you’re running macOS Catalina), you may be able to recover your text messages from there. And even if you think you didn’t back
          up your messages, it’s worth a few […]</p>

        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- This is the background shape I am animating -->
  <div class="blog-plate"></div>
  </div><!-- ./plate-wrap -->


  <div class="container">
    <div class="another-section">
      Content within the same section
      <!-- Added content here is pushed further down below -->
    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<section id="recipe-section">
  <div>
    Next Section Here, Why am I so far down?
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#blog-section {
  width: 100%;
}
.plate-wrap{
  padding-top: 7rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
}
.blog-display {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.blog-img img {
  text-align: center;
}

.blog-text {
  margin: auto 5rem;
  color: white;
}

.blog-text a {
  color: white;
}

.blog-plate {
  background: #0c3445;
  top: 0;
  height: 80%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: 20s ease-in 7s infinite blogmove;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes blogmove {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
  }
}
/* Recipe Section */
#recipe-section {
  padding-top: 7rem;
}
```

I have also made a jsfiddle with same code for your reference, you can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oxhe62a5/)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Exactly what I was going for! Thank you for providing this explanation. Thank you so much, be safe and be well! :D

Comment: Glad to be of help, and you too stay safe and well.